# CSS two class on my div

Tags: css

i have this div:

```
<div class="page-template-default logged-in"></div>
```

I need to apply a class like this:

```
.page-template-default .logged-in {
}
```

But this don't work, why?

Comment: Because that selector would apply to an element with the class `logged-in` *inside* an element with the class `page-template-default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the selector without a space in between.

```
.page-template-default.logged-in {

 }
```

That's a chained class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a comma:

```
.page-template-default, .logged-in {
}
```

Comment: That would apply to either, not both.

Comment: ...thanks? My point is *that may not be what the OP wants*, and you should at least *mention* this so that they can determine which answer is most appropriate.